# Cupressus with brown branches

Tags: trees, tree-care, insects, bugs

[image][image]enter image description here

I live in Sintra Portugal (by the sea) so with mild climate type 9. The terrain is sandy but I tend to fertilize annually and I have drop-by-drop irrigation. This year my four Cupressus sempervirens appeared with brown branches and inside they are starting to turn almost black. I tried to see if it was a sucking bug, but I can't see any. Some help?

Comment: picture please!